# Как индексировать сохраняемый файл Qimage

Tags: c++, c, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Я нарезаю картинку в цикле и сохраняю ее таким способом

```
mapimage.save("test.bmp","BMP");
```

Но вот в чем проблема . Я ожидал что она будет сохраняться примерно вот таким образом:test.bmp test1.bmp test2.bmp test3.bmp test4.bmp
А программа просто перезаписывает один и тот же файл. Как быть?

Comment: Разумеется она перезаписывает один и тот же файл. Ведь в качестве имени всегда используется "test.bmp". Почему бы вдруг программа стала использовать другие имена?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте цикл

```
for (int i = 1; i <= <number_of_parts>; ++i)
{
    mapimage.save(QString("test%1.bmp").arg(i),"BMP");
}
```

где `number_of_parts` - количество частей вашей нарезки